# Intermediate Forms Between Parabolic and Hyperbolic PDE (numerically)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, wave-equation

Greetings MSE community,

I have recently conducted some rudimentary experiments in matlab coding of PDE's. I have explicit and implicit numerical solutions to both the heat and the wave equation, for some mundane boundary (and initial) conditions.

Basically, solved numerically $ \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\ $ and $\ \ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},\ $ $u(x,t):[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

I am now curious about fractional (more specifically, non-integer) time derivatives.

$\ \ \ \frac{\partial^\alpha u}{\partial t^\alpha}=k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},\ $ for $\alpha\in[1,2].$

I am wondering if there is a continuous deformation between the two surface plots of the heat and wave equations as $\alpha$ moves from 1 to 2. Thus, my task is to code the following: $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\displaystyle\int^{t}_{0}(t-s)^{\beta-1}u(x,s)\ ds\ =\ k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
where $0 < \beta \leq 1$. The above operator contains a "fractional integral", so that $\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial t^\alpha}=\frac{\partial^{2-\beta}}{\partial t^{2-\beta}}.$

This is somewhat beyond the scope of the initial experiment, and maybe too ambitious to someone with my programming skills. Where do I begin, since I cannot simply discretize the time derivative, which is what worked in the previous experiments? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2345v1.pdf) is helpful.

The idea is the following. Let 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \int_0^t (t-s)^{\beta-1}u(x,s)\,ds
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
I(x,t)=  \int_0^t (t-s)^{\beta-1}u(x,s)\,ds
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(x,t) \approx \frac{1}{\Delta t^2}( I(x,t-\Delta t) -2I(x,t)+I(x,t+\Delta t))
\end{align}
The method is explained in detail in the paper. I hope this helps!

Comment: the link is indeed very helpful... i see that better minds have been here before.

Comment: It's just a lucky coincidence, I'm currently writing (or starting to write) my master thesis about numerical methods for fractional diffusion equations. This was just one method I've looked at. Good luck!

Comment: follow up question: how do we make sense of the initial conditions? I did manage to get an output that looks like a wave eqn for $\beta \approx 0$, and resembles a heat eqn for $\beta = 1$. it is bothering me that there should be only one initial condition for the heat equation, and two for the wave equation; these are not necessarily compatible. it does not make sense to have $1\frac{1}{2}$ initial conditions.

Comment: I can't really speak for the case where $\beta=1$ because I've only been working on the fractional diffusion equation. However there, you always have only one initial condition, if I'm not mistaken. I see the problem when going from the diffusiont, to the wave equation. If I find something new, I'll let you know. Maybe you could also reply if you find something.

Comment: Maybe (just my first result) [equation (3) and (4)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0512028v1.pdf) help in this case.